# Let $f_n: [a,b] \rightarrow \Bbb R$ be uniformly bounded continuous functions with $F_n(x) = \int_a^{x}f_n(t)dt, x\in [a,b]$

Tags: real-analysis

Problem: Let the functions $f_n: [a,b] \Bbb \rightarrow R$ be uniformly bounded continuous functions. Set $F_n(x) = \int_a^{x}f_n(t)dt, x\in [a,b]$. Prove that $F_n$ has a uniformly convergent subsequence.

What I know is that I need to show that the set of these functions is equicontinuous and pointwise bounded.

I believe it is true that the $F_n$ are uniformly continuous by FTC 1, and uniformly bounded implies pointwise bounded.

What I am not sure is how to show that the $F_n$ are equicontinuous. Hints appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There exists $M$ such that $|f_n(t)|<M$, $|\int_a^xf_n(t)dt-\int_a^yf_n(t)dt|=|\int_y^xf_n(t)dt|=|f_n(c_n)(y-x)|<M|x-y|$.